# Mercury editor not saving edited values in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mercury-editor

I followed [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor) Tutorial to set up mercury editor.

mercuy.js

```
$(window).bind('mercury:ready', function() {
  var link = $('#mercury_iframe').contents().find('#edit_link');
  Mercury.saveUrl = link.data('save_url');
  link.hide();
});

$(window).bind('mercury:saved', function() {
  window.location = window.location.href.replace(/\/editor\//i, '/');
});
```

views/quotations/show.html.erb

```
<p><%= link_to "Edit Page", "/editor" + request.path, id: "edit_link", data: {save_url: mercury_update_quotation_path(@quotation)} %></p>
```

mercury.html.erb

```
  new Mercury.PageEditor(saveUrl, {
    saveStyle:  'form', // 'form', or 'json' (default json)
    saveMethod: null, // 'PUT', or 'POST', (create, vs. update -- default PUT)
    visible:    true  // boolean - if the interface should start visible or not
  });
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :quotations  do
    member { post :mercury_update}
  end
```

It shows the following error

```
Mercury was unable to save to the url: http://localhost:3000/quotations/1
```

Console output

```
Started PUT "/quotations/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-07 19:20:49 +0530

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'update' could not be found for QuotationsController):
```

It worked well for static id's but not like this. Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling you

```
ActionNotFound
```

Meaning you are missing the mercury_update in your QuotationsController. Try adding

```
def mercury_update
  quote = Quotations.find(params[:id])
  quote.FIELD_FROM_YOUR_DB = params[:content][:quotation_content][:value]
  quote.save!
  render text:""#tells mercury of successful save (I think)
end
```

If that doesn't work, try checking your console for the the parameters mercury is passing around. It should look something like

```
Started PUT "/quotations/1/mercury_update" for ...
  Parameters:{"content"=>{...}}
```

Notice that it is a PUT request, that's what Mercury is telling you that it's doing. Thus the route needs to be updated

```
resources :quotations do
  member do
    put 'mercury_update' #this may change your path to mercury_update_quotation_page_path(@quotation)
  end
end
```

Also, ensure that resources :quotations is not defined twice in config/routes.rb. I defined it following that tutorial and then ran

```
rails g scaffold quotations
```

in order to auto-generate views and such. This command defined quotations again at the top of my config/routes.rb as

```
resources :quotations
#...
resources :quotations do #... This was my definition
```

thus ignoring my definition with the member 'mercury_update'.

Finally, let me know if your saved response is working, as mine is not. GL!